# Can we resend messages to multiple Kafka partitions

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a stateful application which maintains sessions with users. There are 5 instances of this application.

Here are the topics:
All topics have 5 partitions.

`topic1`
`topic2`
`topic3`

Topic1 and topic2 are used for building a state store and global ktable respectively. Both topics use user name as message key. Data in these topics are produced by the application instances themselves.

Now another application produce data to topic3 with same user name as message key.

My expectation is that it will be going to the same partition which is consumed by the instance who has that user in its local state store. Is this right?

For each message it should also be processed by other instances who has this user sessions. So is it right design if the instance finds partitions listened by other instances and forward the message to other partitions?

Is this scalable design or is it preferable to broadcast all messages to all partitions (diff consumer group) and instance decide should it be processed or not

Comment: By definition of a global ktable, the instances will coordinate which node is correct to query, remotely, should the local one not have the data you are looking for. So, not sure it matters which consumer gets the data. Regarding the question title: yes, if you use a custom partitioner

Comment: It matters which instance gets it. All the instances which has the user session must get the message. I think we need to implement custom solution to resend same message  to multiple partitions. Is it possible otherwise with Kafka?

Comment: You are asking two things. 1) Can you send data to multiple partitions? Yes, with a custom partitioner. Otherwise, same event always goes to same partition. You can also assign specific partitions to consumers, although not within KStreams. 2) RPC calls to remote statestores are a pattern in the KStreams documentation on GlobalKTables; if the key is not present locally, it'll fetch remotely, thus "global" lookups over all store instances

Comment: RPC lookup in remote store is not my question. There are two ways I can achieve sending message to multiple instances - 1) use different consumer group for instances and let all instances receive all messages and ignore what is not required. 2) use state store to find partitions of instances which should process and then manually send to specific partitions. Which one is efficient?

Comment: Just to clarify sending to specific partitions is not based on key presence in state store but app specific user sessions

Comment: I don't think custom partitioner would work since partition info are know only to consumer

Comment: In order to have a ktable, you need a key. You cannot send a null key to one. Partition info is known to a producer. It is decided by the Partitioner interface.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218589/discussion-between-cppcoder-and-onecricketeer).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you really need to send the data to multiple partitions...

1. If you have a GlobalKTable (or global-store), each instance will read *all* topic partitions and thus materialize a full copy of the data locally. (Thus, if you really use Interactive Queries, no remote calls are made as all data is local anyway.)

Thus, you are left with two (regular) input topics.

2. The partition assignment in Kafka Streams is different to the partition assignment of a regular consumer. In you case, with each topic having 5 partitions, 5 tasks will be created, and each task will read one partition from one input topic, eg, task-0 will read t1-p0 and t3-p0, task-1 will read t1-p1 and t3-p1, etc. Therefore, if your input data is partitioned by "user name" all data for a single user to processed by the same task.